# How to jump to R source code with ESS?

Tags: ess, r

**Q:** how can I get to the source code of R packages using ESS?

When I'm working with elisp, I can access the source code for any
package easily with `find-library` or by following the links in
`find-function` or `find-variable`.

I'd like to be able to do the same thing with R
via [Emacs Speaks Statistics (`ess`)](https://ess.r-project.org/).
How can I get `ess` to send me to the source code of a given
function/package?

Answer (score 1):

I have had some decent success with `ess-r-xref`.  `(require 'ess-r-xref)` and then `M-.` (`xref-find-definitions`) with point on some symbol.  It should prompt you to save a TAGS file.  Then `M-.` should do what you want.

Check out https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Xref.html

**Alternately:**

I'm a big proponent of the Language Server Protocol.  There's an R [language server](https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver#language-clients) that should work with `lsp-mode`, but does not yet support find definition/reference requests AFAIK.  I would recommend monitoring that project.

Comment: `ess-build-tags-for-directory`, bound to `C-c C-e t` and `C-c C-e C-t` is helpful for setting up xref.

Comment: Did you have to enable `xref-etags-mode` to make it work with `ess-r-xref` ?

Comment: @schatten I did not.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably old, but I found out how to do it just looking at this question.

I installed ESS under Emacs 26.3 and I didn't do anything particular with this. It seems `ess-r-xref` works without doing any specific setting.

If do `M-.` or  `M-x xref-find-definitions` and I am asked what I'm looking for ( auto-completion works nicely), than it opens a new buffer with the file containing the object I am looking for.